# Video effects/manipulation library?

Tags: video, video-processing

I've been trying to find a good library for manipulating video, for example, gluing clips together, addings captions, transitions between clips etc. So far I have no been able to find anything promising. If it runs on linux thats a plus, does not have to be free. To be clear, im looking for some form of api/library, not a video editing tool.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of CLI tools that come to mind.

- [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org): arguablely the most popular tool for such things, although it might not be exactly what you need:
- [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html): it does some interesting things
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/): Another popular and powerful tool

Comment: Thanks Stu, Im familiar with all of the above, the closest thing I have found to what i was looking for is mlt, http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/Features